# Nautilus reacts slowly, information about opened directory disappears

Tags: gnome, performance, nautilus

I use the fallback mode in GNOME 3 and Nautilus.

When you select *Menu - Location - Home* (or any other directory), Nautilus opens this directory. I can move between directories without problems.

However, the information about the opened directory – in the picture, "Otwieranie ..." – disappears after about 10 seconds, and the mouse changes to the shape a clock.

[image]

It's pretty annoying. How do I fix this?